# Sound.play() crashing without parameters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, audio-recording

I am doing the following in my code:

```
        _sound = new Sound();
        _sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, handlePlaybackSampleData );
        _soundChannel = _sound.play();
```

Usually this should result in the Sound calling the handle... function when it wants to play so that I can insert my own generated ByteArray for the sound. 
But it doesn't even call that function and sometimes (!!!) crashes instead with an:

```
Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
```

I have no idea why this is happening. In all examples it works exactly like that.
It also doesn't make too much sense as all parameters in play() are optional anyway.

Before that happens, I am recording the microphone input to a buffer, and then want to playback what I have recorded, which is what all this is for.

Edit:
Here is the function:

```
    public function handlePlaybackSampleData(p_sampleEvent:SampleDataEvent) :void 
    {
        // Read data until either MAX_SAMPLES or all available samples are reached.
        var i:int = 0;
        var data :Number = 0;
        while( i < 8192 )
        {
            if( _lastRecord.bytesAvailable )
            {
                data = _lastRecord.readFloat();
                p_sampleEvent.data.writeFloat(data);
                p_sampleEvent.data.writeFloat(data);
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe i do not see it, but which sound do you want to play? as I see you have no source.

Comment: Can you share the `handlePlaybackSampleData` function code?

Comment: I edited it. Another problem is that IF it works, the sound playback is waaaay too fast. But I'll make another topic for that problem.

Comment: Sounds like your sample rate isn't correct. I remember reading of a way to change it somewhere on here.

Comment: Yep, the sample rate was a problem, see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380499/recording-audio-works-playback-way-too-fast) Solving that also somehow solved this problem. Can't really explain how. Maybe it was just a slightly f*cked up compilation and restarting everything fixed it. Hard to say, but it's gone now. Thanks for the help, anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have this question get an "official answer", here is what happened:

The sample rate was a problem, as you can see in a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380499/recording-audio-works-playback-way-too-fast). Solving that also somehow solved this problem.

Unfortunately, I can't really explain how. Maybe it was just a slightly f*cked up compilation and restarting everything fixed it. In any case, it is gone now.